# What can you say about the Linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

if $T:V \to V$ be a linear transformation and the composite $T(T)=0$,then $T$?

1) Kernel of $T$ is subset of image of $T$.

2)Image of $T$ is subset of kernel of $T$.

3) $T$ is a zero transformation.

4)$T$ is a non singular linear transformation.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Can you at least rule out some of the possible answers?  Also, "$T:v \to T$" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: as you are new to the site:  People here tend to not respond well (or at all) to questions like this that look like standard homework problems and which show no effort at all.  Please edit your post to show what you have tried and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Voting to close the question.  If you can, please edit your post to show what you have tried and where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T (T)=0$, then you can conclude that $Im ( T)$ is a subset of $Ker (T)$.

To show: $Im(T) \subset Ker(T)$

Let $y \in Im (T)$ then there exists $x \in V$ such that $T(x)=y$,

now, $T(T)=0 \Rightarrow T(T(x))=0 \Rightarrow T(y)=0 \Rightarrow y\in Ker (T) .$

Thus,$Im(T) \subset Ker(T).$